# is_home() || is_front_page() not working

Tags: wordpress

I have already tried everything, and searched in every place. Why doesn't it work?

This is my functions.php, the page always show "else".

My code:

```
wp_reset_query();
if(is_home() || is_front_page())
    die("if");
die("else");
```

Comment: Add the code to your question. Don't give a screenshot of your code. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/248567

Comment: Sorry,I didn't know that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use a `hook` in your `function.php` to execute a piece of code before everything else like this:

```
add_action('wp', 'check_home');
function check_home() {
    if(is_home() || is_front_page()) {
        die("yes");
    } else {
        die("no");
    }
}
```

You should never just write php statements that stand on it's own in your `functions.php` file. Only use it to define functions that your want to use somewhere else in your code, or define `hooks` like `actions` and `filters` with corresponding functions.

If you want to know more about hooks read [this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Hooks)

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Comment: Good answer. But i want to now from where you got this point "You should never just write php statements that stand on it's own in your functions.php"