# Call to undefined function is_single() , is_home() wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Currently I am coding in my own custom plugin. For some reason I can't use conditional tags inside my function. For example

```
 function check_home() {
    if(is_home()) {
       $my_val=1;
    } else {
     $my_val=2;
    }
    return $my_val;
  }
```

It's returning following error

> **Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function is_home()**

I checked and I found a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43393813/is-home-is-front-page-not-working) & it is working fine.

It saying to add this `add_action('wp', 'check_home');`

But now I want to get the value of function to variable. But it is showing error.

```
 add_action('wp', 'check_home');
 function check_home() {
    if(is_home()) {
       $my_val=1;
    } else {
     $my_val=2;
    }
    return $my_val;
  }
  
  $my_ver = check_home();
  echo $my_ver;
```

Then it showing following error.

> **Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function is_home()**

Now how can i solve this error ? What i am missing ?

Comment: Everything is running fine on my end.

Comment: thank you. This is related to plugin development . This code i write inside plugin . If you read my question you will understand that at the beginning i got error Call to undefined function is_home() but it is solved by adding add_action('wp', 'check_home');
Now please read the second point from question . If you note see this 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43393813/is-home-is-front-page-not-working then you will understand